# org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Multiple 'property' definitions

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring and trying to get familiar with the concepts. My purpose is to create multiple instances of the below-mentioned class.

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private int itemID;
    private String itemName;


    public int getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }

    public void setItemID(int itemID) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return itemName;
    }
}
```

In the config.xml I'm trying to set the property values in a below-mentioned way.

```
    <bean name="item" class="com.manasa.spring.springcore.task1.Item">
        <property name="itemID">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemName">
            <value>Sandisk Pendrive</value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemID">
            <value>2</value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemName">
            <value>Dell Keyboard</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="cart" class="com.manasa.spring.springcore.task1.ShoppingCart"
        p:id="1">
        <property name="items">
            <map>
                <entry key-ref="item">
                    <value>2</value>
                </entry>

                <entry key-ref="item">
                    <value>1</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

By doing so, I am facing this issue:

```
> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unexpected failure during bean definition parsing
Offending resource: class path resource [com/manasa/spring/springcore/task1/mapconfig.xml]
Bean 'item'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Multiple 'property' definitions for property 'itemID'
Offending resource: class path resource [com/manasa/spring/springcore/task1/mapconfig.xml]
Bean 'item'
    -> Property 'itemID'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:562)
```

Could anyone please suggest on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is here :

```
<property name="itemID">
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property name="itemName">
    <value>Sandisk Pendrive</value>
</property>
<property name="itemID">
    <value>2</value>
</property>
<property name="itemName">
    <value>Dell Keyboard</value>
</property>
```

I don't think it is allowed to set values for the same properties several times. When Spring parses this config it actually calls `setXXX` (appropriate setter) and you are not allowed to reassign values for properties in XML config.

So you need to remove duplicates. Result :

```
<bean name="item" class="com.manasa.spring.springcore.task1.Item">
    <property name="itemID">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemName">
        <value>Sandisk Pendrive</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And if you need several instances (more `Item` objects) you need to create more beans (add more `<bean> ... </bean>` sections). E.g.

```
<bean id="someOtherInstance" name="someOtherInstance" class="com.manasa.spring.springcore.task1.Item">
    <property name="itemID">
        <value>123</value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemName">
        <value>Some Other Value</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Remember that you need to give them different ids (names) so Spring could distinguish.

Comment: The id should be set on both Item-beans (to different values of course), and should be wired in the key-refs in the items-Map of the cart, as well.